# Can't get post data from Javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, symfony

it's my first post, I'm stuck on this, please help.

On a page I've got two symfony forms (without classes) from which I get some data that I store in arrays. The first form is for a contract, and the other form is used to fill a datatable of products with their data (price, quantity, etc.). On each of those forms, I've got a submit button that I manage with ajax (onclick) to get to the step forward of the pagen while preventing the data processing. The datatable listing the products is the ending step of the page and under it I have a validation button that I want to use to submit all the data from the 1st form and the datatable (in which are the data from the second form) that I previously have stored in arrays.

I know two ways of doing this ($.post with jQuery and the other with ajax but both don't work). I manage to redirect to the other page but I can't get the $_POST (or $request) data.

Here's the 'final button' ajax part (with the other way I tried in comments) :

```
$("#btn_final").click(function( e ) {

    // console.log(produits);

    // $.post(
    //     path_confirm, 
    //     { produits: produits },
    //     function() {
    //         window.location.replace(path_confirm);
    //     }
    // );


    $.ajax({
        url: path_confirm,
        type: 'POST',
        // dataType: 'html',
        data: { 'produits' : produits, 'contrat' : contrat },
        // context: this,
        // dataType: "json",
        success:function(data) {
            window.location.replace(path_confirm);
            // console.log(data);
        },
        error:function(data) {
            alert("erreur");
        }
    });
```

and here's my basic controller supposedly getting the data :

```
public function getData(Request $request) {

    // $produits = $request->request->get('produits');
    // $contrat = $request->request->get('contrat');

    if ($_POST) {
       var_dump($_POST);die;
    } else {
        echo "<h1> no data :/ </h1>";die;
    }
```

I get redirected to the page but the answer is "no data".
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Are `produits` and `contrat` defined?

Comment: Yes @FelDev, right here `data: { 'produits' : produits, 'contrat' : contrat }`

Comment: Yes, I did a 'console.log' just before the .click() function to be sure they are defined before putting them in the ajax function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with one simple line thanks to a jQuery plugin called "redirect". If that can help someone up later :

What you need is simply import the script from here in your view :
https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect/blob/master/jquery.redirect.js

Then simply write :

```
$.redirect(url, [values, [method, [target, [traditional, [redirectTop]]]]])
```

In my case, I wrote :

```
$.redirect(path_confirm, {'produits': produits, 'contrat': contrat, 'pj': pj, 'idclient': id});
```

and it works.

Answer (score 2):

Because the redirection causes the POST data to be lost., The AJAX request is expecting to return the information via AJAX. Add a prevent default to stop the redirection:

```
$("#btn_final").click(function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Then observe the AJAX request on the developer tools. If `$('#btn_final')` is a submit button you will need to utilize the `.submit()` handler.

If you plan to do a redirect to the PHP script processing the data there is absolutely no need for jQuery or AJAX at all.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your quick answer. It wasn't a submit button (I thought it was ok to do it like that), this is why I wrote a ".click()" function.
I've tried with a submit button and wrote a ".submit()" function but now when clicking on the button it just doesn't do anything.
I also have put the "e.preventDefault()" line

Comment: OK - then you can just use a button, no need for submit. Where are you setting your post variables?

Comment: The problem is the redirection inside the success callback. @HalimEntation You're first making an Ajax request to the URL with POST parameters, then discarding the result and redirecting to the same URL which makes a new GET request without any parameters. What you're seeing in the browser is the result of this second request.

Comment: My array "contrat" is defined before the ".submit()" function of the first form, and my array 'produits' is defined before the ".submit()" function of the second form.
During the two ".submit()" functions, I just push the data to the arrays and after the two submit() functions I get the two arrays filled.

Comment: Alright @JJJ I think I got it, but how am I supposed to redirect after posting the data ? I shouldn't redirect in the success callback ?

Comment: You *can* redirect in the call back, but don't expect to see your post data unless you commit that data to some sort of storage you can query for the data. For most use cases you shouldn't use AJAX at all if you plan to redirect.

Comment: I don't really see the point of making an Ajax request at all if you want to redirect there immediately anyway. Just have the HTML form post the data there normally and it'll work out of the box.

Comment: Alright thank you @@@JayBlanchard and @JJJ, so I'm not supposed to use Ajax for this. I did this because the products are stored dynamically in the datatable but the user can delete some products (rows), so before I click the final submit button I don't know yet what are the data. The final button is supposed to get the final data, transfer it to a controller and redirect to the next page.